# Retrieve model worker index in SageMaker Python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

According to the SM python SDK [documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/64f600d677872fe8656cdf25d68fc4950b2cd28f/src/sagemaker/mxnet/model.py#L107) one model worker will be allocated per vCPU. Is there a way to get an index number for each worker? That way it will be possible to distribute workers to GPUs. Example: 32 workers on a 4 GPU machine would yield 8 dedicated workers per GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The number of workers is usually an env var we pass in the inference toolkit to the multi-model-server: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_inference/model_server.py#L151

It does not expose an interface to get index number for each workers, but when you are making inference with SageMaker, each worker should have different colors in the printing logs thus you can differentiate them.